# Select range with VBA - got stuck

Tags: excel, vba

I got little project in VBA and stuck on below topic.

I need to select range from searched value to first empty cell in H column.

Selected range should looks like this

Selected Range in Excel:
[image: Selected Range in Excel]

I searched for specific value in column A and if I found it it's being set as first cell in range. ( It works)

Then I need to find last cell in range which is first empty cell in last column.

This is what I've found and try to use

```
Sub Button()

    Dim StringToFind As String

    StringToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter string to find", "Find string")

    Worksheets("SS19").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Select

    Set cell = Selection.Find(What:=StringToFind, After:=ActiveCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    cell.Select

    With Worksheets("SS19")

        Set rr = .Range(ActiveCell, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))

        With rr
            rr.Parent.Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Select
        End With

    End With

    If cell Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("SS19").Activate
        MsgBox "String not found"
    End If
```

I tried to searched for first empty cell in prevously selected range so it won't search the whole column but it doesn't work.

Comment: It would help to ensure row numbers and column letters are visible in the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim StringToFind As String
StringToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter string to find", "Find string")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws
        Dim findCel As Range
        Set findCel = .Range("A:A").Find(StringToFind, , , xlWhole, , , False, , False)

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = .Range(findCel.Address).Offset(, 7).End(xlDown).Row + 1

        Dim rr As Range
        Set rr = .Range("A" & findCel.Row & ":" & "H" & lRow)

        rr.Select
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that using the worksheet's match function is easier than Range.Find when searching a single column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button()

    Dim stringToFind As String, m As Variant

    Worksheets("SS19").Activate
    stringToFind = Application.InputBox("Enter string to find", "Find string", Type:=xlTextValues)

    With Worksheets("SS19")

        m = Application.Match(stringToFind, .Range("A:A"), 0)

        If Not IsError(m) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(m + 1, "H")) Then
                .Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(m, "H").End(xlDown).Offset(1)).Select
            Else
                .Range(.Cells(m, "A"), .Cells(m, "H").Offset(1)).Select
            End If
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

Using .End(xlDown) could be problematic if the first cell under row *m* in column H was blank and this should be checked for or you might find the selection reaching too far, possibly all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet. Checking for a non-blank cell will catch this potential problem.